# Can you buy and sell shares between different markets?

Tags: stocks

Let's say if I purchase a share that is both listed on TSX and NYSE. Is it possible for me to buy on one of the markets and sell it on the other?

The reason I am doing this is to avoid currency exchange fees. Is there any downside to this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is known as "Journaling". If your broker supports it and that the two shares are of the same class, it can save FX fee.